# Avoid Oracle schema name with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using the [Official Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) SQL and [Entity Framework](https://packages.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/) driver to read the database. But when reading the database it prefixes the table name with "dbo".:

```
SELECT
*
FROM "dbo"."Woningen"
```

Without the "dbo". prefix the code works fine, with, it causes the error "table or view does not exist". This is probably because the user isn't 'dbo', so it does not have access to that schema. This is the Entity Framework code that I'm using:

```
[Table("Woningen")]
public class Woningen
```

I've tried updating the Oracle nuget package but then it comes up with the error "Connection string is not well-formed". So it probably has the same error as before, it just failed sooner. This is the connectionString format I used:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
  providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
  connectionString="USER ID=testUser;PASSWORD=password;  
  Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=serverUrl)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Database)));"/>
```

I can see three possible solutions to this problem, but have no idea how to implement them:

1. Manipulate Entity Framework to exclude schema names from queries
2. Give my user access to the schema
3. Update the driver and fix the connectionstring format, if anyone knows how the format changed..

Note that current code already works in production so the current version should be fine. The database and it's user are new, so the problem could be with how they are created.

Comment: You can specify the appropriate schema to use in EF, if that helps? EF6+ `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(“your schema name”);`

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thanks, that's the solution, using the username as the schema name. If you make it into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the schema that Entity Framework uses. See below

If you are using Entity Framework 6+ you can use the following

```
public class Context : DbContext
{  
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Set a default schema for ALL tables
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YourSchemaName");
    }
}
```

If you wish to set a schema on a specific table...

```
[Table("Woningen"), Schema = "YourSchemaName")]
public class Woningen { }
```

If you are using EF5

```
public class Context : DbContext
{    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
         // Unfortunately you have to specify each table you want to set a schema for...
         modelBuilder.Entity<Woningen>().ToTable("Woningen", "YourSchemaName");
    } 
}
```

Comment: any recommendation for database first approach? as, in almost every case, schema of dev env is different than prod env.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Perhaps store schema name in the webconfig/application settings?

Comment: thank you for quick reply! I tried it but wasn't able to connect all parts well. would be really helpful if you can share a blog or link with code, as guide?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599965/1350913) answer out. It tells you how to access the applicationsettings within web.config.

Comment: problem is, there's no option, as far as I researched, in Entity Framework to pass schema at run time for DB first approach. Thank you for the help though, much appreciated.

Comment: What if you already created a migration on local machine? There already will be a schema name embedded into migration script. So if you run migration on prod - it will fail. Ideally I would want to avoid specifying any schemas at all. Is it possible?